# Creating a java pacakge in vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

When I create a java package inside the `src` folder in the java project I am working on, without using any package, everything works just fine, just when I create that package folder and move all my java files to it  though all the files have the package name correct in them and everything else is correct, but I get these 2 errors below, i will provide you with some screenshots to better understand the situation.

```
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            Circle2D c1 = new Circle2D(2,2,5.5);
            ^
  symbol:   class Circle2D
  location: class Main
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            Circle2D c1 = new Circle2D(2,2,5.5);
                              ^
  symbol:   class Circle2D
  location: class Main
Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(c1.getArea()+" "+ c1.getPerimeter()+" "+c1.contains(3,3)+" "+c1.contains(new Circle2D(4, 5, 10.5)));
                                                                                                            ^
  symbol:   class Circle2D
  location: class Main
Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(c1.overlaps(new Circle2D(3,5,2.3)));
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Circle2D
  location: class Main
4 errors
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

The only thing that worked is instead of running the code with "Run Code" button of the code runner extension I used "Run Java" but I don't like to use it because it prints so much clutter and using the code runner features gives a clean output.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text. Why do all this screenshots show different contents of `src\exercises`?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your classes are trying to find each other in the *current* directory.

To "route" them in the right way:

1. Create a new directory in your project folder and call it `.vscode`. Visual Studio Code will orient on files in it when decides where to look for your `.java` files.
2. Create `settings.json` file in `Project1.vscode`.
3. Fill `settings.json` with the following text:

```json
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

[You're supposed to get result like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydEKt.png)

If it stil does not work go to settings (Ctrl+,), type "launch" and get a single [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNyQs.png). Selecting it will send you to global settings file, where you should find `"configurations": []` and fill `[]` with the following:

```json
    {
        "name": "Java",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [
            ""
        ],
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "classpath": [
            ".",
            "${fileDirname}"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: when creating a java project in vs code , it automatically creates a .vscode containing this settings.json with the same content you provided, the problem is persistent even with this

Comment: Have you tried creating/configuring `launch.json`?

Comment: no i didn't, what should i write in it ?

Comment: I cannot be sure, but I would suggest this one:
`
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                ""
            ],
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
`

Comment: I can also put almost empty working workspace in a GitHub repository and send you a link.

Comment: I left all instructions in the answer (in a more readable style)

Comment: i am getting " the ... property is not allowed " warning

Comment: I have no ideas how to fix it, sorry :(
Perhaps Code Runner is not suitable for project management. But if you REALLY need to run project via Code Runner, you could try plugging in a project management extension like Maven.
Btw, why do you want to use exactly Code Runner?

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that worked is instead of running the code with "Run Code" button of the code runner extension I used "Run Java"

You should use the official [Extension Pack for Jav](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)a and use it to execute your java project (**Run Java**). If you use other extensions that cause errors, it has nothing to do with Java.

*Code Runner* is only used for executing code, it doesn't have much advantage for complete projects, please use official extensions.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial